# selected item value from Bootstrap DropDown with specific ID

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown generated on a page and javascript onclick to capture change and send a POST resuest to the server.

The value inside 'a' is the playlist id, which expected by server

my selectvalue inside JS is always 0. how to retrive the value inside a?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btnchanneldropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Select Playlist
    </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="ulchanneldropdown">
        <li><a value="3002">Play List 01</a></li>
        <li><a value="3003">Play List 02</a></li>
        <li><a value="3004">Play List 03</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Jscript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ulchanneldropdown').on('click', 'li a',function(){

var selectvalue = $(this).data('value');

$.post('functions/playlist_table1.php', { value: inputValue },function(data,status){
  var targetDiv = document.getElementById('playlist_here');
  targetDiv.innerHTML = data;
      });
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) :

```
var inputValue = $(this).attr('value');
```

`data("value")` is used to get `data-value="test"` attribute.

And as pointed by @u_mulder, you have to change `selectvalue` to `inputValue`, or change into your `{ value: inputValue }` to `{ value: selectvalue }`.

Comment: As a side note - `value: inputValue` should be `value: selectvalue`

Comment: one more thing now my POST page I get a error saying Undefined index: value for $listid = $_POST["value"];

Comment: yes `<?php
$listid = $_POST['value'];` and then thw sql and php to create html

Comment: my mistake I chnaged the value to li for testing. now its working.

Comment: @Chamisxs Good :) I was testing :)